# Problem installing gems

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, datamapper

I had recently used datamapper, and then all of a sudden it didn't work.  I keep getting this error:

```
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- dm-mysql-adapter (LoadError)
    from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:163:in `load_adapter'
    from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:133:in `adapter_class'
    from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core/adapters.rb:13:in `new'
    from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/dm-core-1.1.0/lib/dm-core.rb:219:in `setup'
```

Then, when I try to load the dm-mysql-adapter, it gives me this error:

```
/Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I've seen similar error messages when I'm googling, but none of the responses seem to work for me...

Comment: Please post the contents of the mkmf.log file. I think the log will be in /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/dm-mysql-adapter-1.1.0/.

Comment: Hm, I'm missing the dm-mysql-adapter-1.1.0 in the gems directory... but I do have the dm-sqlite-adapter that was giving me the same problem.  It doesn't have a mkmf.log file though.

Comment: How did you install mysql and sqlite? Macports? Homebrew?